# Adding two columns and order it

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have 3 tables as given below:

***users***

```
oauth_uid | name
1         | John Claude
2         | Nick Jonas
3         | Justin Timberlake
```

***test***

```
oauth_id | score
1        | 30
2        | 28
1        | 20
3        | 18
2        | 34
```

***training***

```
oauth_id | score
2        | 3
1        | 8
1        | 2
2        | 18
```

I want to order users by following conditions:

- Select maximum score of a user from test id as test_score
- Select sum of all score of a user from training as tr_score
- Lastly add the above two and order it in descending order

So far I've been able to fulfill first two conditions:

```
select test.oauth_id, max(test.score) as score, users.name
from users inner join
     test
     on test.oauth_id = users.oauth_uid
group by test.oauth_id
order by score desc

select sum(training.score) as tr_score
from training
group by training.oauth_id
order by tr_score desc
```

How can I add both and order it by total score ?

Comment: I cannot understand why a question with an explanation, sample data, and sample code would be downvoted, particularly for a new user to the site.

Comment: the label is wrong is only mysql,sql not php

Comment: Rolled back to previous version to avoid invalidation of given answer. If you have a follow-up question, ask a new one and use this one for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Use subqueries:

```
select u.*, max_score, sum_score,
       (coalesce(max_score, 0) + coalesce(sum_score, 0)) as overall_score
from users u left join
     (select oauth_id, max(score) as max_score
      from test
      group by oauth_id
     ) te
     on te.oauth_id = u.oauth_id left join
     (select oauth_id, sum(score) as sum_score
      from test
      group by oauth_id
     ) tr
     on tr.oauth_id = u.oauth_id
order by overall_score desc;
```

Comment: I've added a time_taken column in test table. Is it possible to order it by time_taken also, in case overall score is same ?

Comment: @ExodiaTech . . . It is rude to change the question after it has been answered.  If you have a new question, it should be asked as a new question.

Comment: please look into this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47159791/adding-two-columns-and-order-it-follow-up?noredirect=1#comment81269261_47159791